# Can't remove any existing lock

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

I was trying to install Git with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Then I get this error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

`E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/)`, is another process using it?

I read somewhere that this commamd is to be used to remove any lock

```
sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

But upon entering this command my PC just goes blank... Nothing happens.

and i am running on ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS (PRECISE PANGOLIN)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you use, can you describe it please + have you checked here out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/how-do-i-fix-a-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-problem/15469#15469

Comment: UBUNTU 12.0.4 LTS (PRECISE PANGOLIN)

Answer (score 1):

I see pretty much all the answers recommend deleting the lock. I don't recommend doing that as a first measure; maybe if there is no alternative. The lock is placed when an apt process is running, and is removed when the process completes. If there is a lock with no apparent process running, this may mean the process got stuck for some reason.

If you try

```
ps aux | grep apt
```

that will catch processes containing the word apt, at least. If you see an apt-get process or an aptitude process that looks stuck, you can try

```
kill processnumber
```

and if that doesn't work try

```
kill -9 processnumber
```

This should kill the process and may remove the lock. Killing an apt or aptitude process is harmless unless it is actually in the middle of package installation. In any case, if the process got stuck, you probably don't have a choice but to kill it.

Comment: In my case it was automagically solved after second or third reboot, but not after the first one... o.O? Anyway, do try to complete processes (e.g., `sudo dpkg --configure -a`) and other harmless things (e.g., opening and closing software center, synaptic, software updates, etc.) before killing running processes. And try killing processes before force-deleting the lock, risking to break your system.

Answer (score -1):

I was having this problem while running shell scripts with vagrant.  I found that a simple `sleep 10` was sufficient to remove the lock.  Thought I'd share in case it helps anyone.

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please use the comment system instead of digging-up questions that are years old.